# Does Chika have a side effect?

Tags: world-trigger

I recently started World Trigger and I was wondering if Chika Amatori has a side effect. It seems that she is able to sense the presence of Neighbors before they come through a portal. Does this count as a side effect or is it just something that people with high amounts of Trion already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least in the anime Chika Amatori has a side effect.  This is shown is episode 6 which was called "Chika Amatori's Side Effect".  Her side effect appears to be at least the ability to sense neighbors searching for her with hostel intent. Note: all sensory improvements due to high amounts of Trion are called side effects and no one so far seems to have the same ones.

Comment: I need to start paying attention to the titles. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SWard, I rarely read titles as they can spoil the episode.  I remembered this one though as I noticed how much they focused on the other dude's side effect instead of hers.

Comment: In the manga, if she has the side effect it’s not explicitly stated.